# How to add logo in firebase ui authentication in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm not able to set custom logo of my app at the signIn activity, while using firebase auth UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the logo using .setLogo() property of AuthUI.getInstance().

[Github firebase authUI Doc.](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md)

```
AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setTheme(R.style.FirebaseLoginTheme)
                        .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                        .setProviders(providers)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Comment: is there anything similar for ios.?